# Matrix representation of linear transformation in different basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Given a linear transformation $$T:V\rightarrow V$$
And given 2 bases $B$ and $C$ of the subspace $V$

Is there any connection between $[T]_B$ and $[T]_C$ (the matrix representation of the transformation in the specified basis)

Does those 2 matrices have the same rank?signature?eigenvalues?
Are they congruence or similar?

Thanks :)

Update:

I'm leaning on thinking that they are congruence but no similar and there for have same rank and signature but not same eigenvaluess

Comment: Could you please put your question in more context: is this a homework question? what have you tried so far?

Comment: it's just me trying to understand fully this field...i have thought about the connection -  $T_b=ST_cS^{-1}$ but was having a bit of a hard time to answer myself on all those questions(rank,sig)

Answer (score 1):

Use that if $T_{B}$ and $T_{C}$ are matrices of the same linear map (or restriction of this map on some subspace of $V$), then exist the matrix $S:T_{B}=ST_{C}S^{-1}$

Comment: I know this equation,but still having a bit of hard time to deduct from it an answer to my questions...

Answer (score -1):

The expression you're looking for is $$B \circ [T]_B \circ B^{-1} = C \circ [T]_C \circ C^{-1}.$$ Let me explain.

The way I like to think of bases is:

> **Definition 0.** A *basis* of $V$ is an isomorphism $\varphi : V \leftarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathrm{dim}(V)}$.

Now suppose we're given:

- A vectorspace $V$
- A natural number $n$ defined by $n = \mathrm{dim}(V)$
- A linear transform $T : V \leftarrow V$.
- Two bases $B$ and $C$ of $V$.

Then we get "matrices" $$B^{-1}\circ T \circ B : \mathbb{R}^n \leftarrow \mathbb{R}^n, \qquad C^{-1} \circ T \circ C : \mathbb{R}^n \leftarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$

which are really just linear transforms. So define:

$$[T]_B = B^{-1} \circ T \circ B, \qquad [T]_C = C^{-1} \circ T \circ C$$

Then obviously, these are related by:

$$B \circ [T]_B \circ B^{-1} = C \circ [T]_C \circ C^{-1}$$

Comment: I have a serious conceptual disagreement with your definition 0: a basis is a set of vectors in $V$, and an isomorphism is a function (linear, invertible). The first is a subset of $V$, while the second is a subset (relation) of $V \times W$, for some set $W = \mathbb{R}^n$. I can see the connection, but I'm not sure students can; carelessly saying that they are the same leads to potential confusion, such as saying that a basis for a subspace is a matrix (when the real meaning is that the vectors given by the columns of a matrix are a basis for the column space).

Comment: @CatalinZara, a basis, to me, isn't a set of vectors, its a *tuple* of vectors. But notice that there's a natural isomorphism between linear transforms $V \leftarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathrm{dim}(V)}$ and elements of $V^{\mathrm{dim}(V)}$. Call this transform $\Phi_V : (V \leftarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathrm{dim}(V)} \;(\mathrm{linear})) \leftarrow V^{\mathrm{dim}(V)}$. You're essentially saying that you'd prefer if I defined a basis to be an element of $V^{\mathrm{dim}(V)}$ satisfying certain properties, rather than an element of $(V \leftarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathrm{dim}(V)} \;(\mathrm{linear}))$...

Comment: ...satisfying certain properties. But look what happens when we do this; suddenly, we have all these useless $\Phi$'s everywhere, e.g. $$[T]_B = \Phi(B)^{-1} \circ T \circ \Phi(B).$$ I think you'd be *very* hard pressed to argue that this increases clarity of expression. I think it's pretty clear that it only decreases clarity.

Comment: @CatalinZara, not convinced? If you do not accept my argument, I'd nonetheless be interested in (cooperatively, without hostility) debating and/or discussing this point.